# Continuous random variable and probability

Tags: random-variables

Suppose that X is a continuous Random variable with probability density function given by

$$
f(x) = x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x + \frac{1}{3} \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq c
$$

What must be the value of c? And why?

Comment: The integral of the probability density is required to be $1$. So take that integral for arbitrary $c$ and set it equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you want the probability of anything happening equal to one. So therefore
$$
\int_{0}^{c} x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x + \frac{1}{3} = 1.
$$